# FQL: select events of this week published by a given page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'd like to do something like:

```
select name from event where creator = 153957741360676
```

but the column creator is not indexable.. how can I do this then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve such information by querying two tables `event_member` and `event`:

```
SELECT name FROM event WHERE eid IN (
  SELECT eid from event_member WHERE uid = me()
) AND creator = me()
```

**Update:**
Since you speaking about events created by page you need to use id of the page instead of `me()`:

```
SELECT name FROM event WHERE eid IN (
  SELECT eid from event_member WHERE uid = 153957741360676
) AND creator = 153957741360676
```

Notes (see [`event` table documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/)):

> Starting July 5th, an access token will be required to access even public events.

Comment: but not events I'm going to.. I want all public events that page publishes! I'm not even logged in..

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover your case with events created by pages

Comment: is this possible to extend this to multiple pages at once? all the events from a list of pages..

Comment: @luca, sure it's possible, just use `IN` clause (like `SELECT eid from event_member WHERE uid IN (PAGE_ID_1, PAGE_ID_2, PAGE_ID_n)`) ;) Be sure to add that clause at appropriate places in the query